# Dynamic width of UIcollectionviewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I had an application in which I am taking the width of the collection view cell as:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20,20,20);
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect screenRect = collection.frame;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / count;
}
```

But now I want on that count the width of the cell needs to be dependent on one parameter, like:

```
NSDictionary *dict=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    float duration=([[dict valueForKey:@"duration"]floatValue]);
```

If duration is 45 then it needs to take 45% of the screen width and like that. Can anybody help me on This when i am trying  `screenWidth * (duration/100.0)` it is looking like this

[image]

Comment: float cellWidth = screenWidth / duration;  try this

Answer (score 0):

If You collectionview just consist of this cells, then i would recommend you to go with section approach.
multiple section for each item , and each section has only one row . By this approach there will be only one row in section and as you wanted even if row size is 10% or less.

keep size approach like below.

```
NSDictionary *dict=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
float duration=([[dict valueForKey:@"duration"]floatValue]);
float cellWidth = screenWidth * (duration/100.0);
```

Comment: but it is giving me equal width for 2 items in a row @Dev_Tandel

Comment: is it possible o upload pic?

Comment: some times it is overlapping.Can u tell me how to specify interim spacing?

Comment: I would really like to see it. Some times visualisation gives better idea

Comment: Hope you are using FlowLayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130662/discussion-between-dev-tandel-and-hacker).

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                      layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
      sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CGRect screenRect = collection.frame;
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        NSDictionary *dict=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        float duration=([[dict valueForKey:@"duration"]floatValue]);
        float cellWidth = duration / 100;

return CGSize(cellWidth, 60);
    }
```

It helps you.